# Understand variance in probability of success in logistic regression as explanatory variable value changes

Tags: regression, probability, logistic

The attached image represents a logistic regression model (green line), with accompanying 95% Wald Confidence intervals (reg lines). The plotted points represent actual data points observed that the regression is based on.

Intuitively, I can understand that because there are few to no observations at the low temperature end, the confidence interval must be wider to achieve the same level of confidence (95%). Basically, we have no data points for that region, so we have to be more and more conservative.

Conversely, we've got tons of data points in the high temperature region, so we can use a smaller band with the same or greater confidence.

I don't know how to corroborate or "prove" this intuition, so to speak.

- I know the expressions for Wald intervals, which are dependent on variance
- I know the expression for variance and its reliance on the variance-covariance matrix
- I've plotted them here, so I know how the terms interact with it to produce the phenomenon
- But how does it actually work that this way from the math, like in general? Not sure if I'm asking the right question, but how can I see mathematically that I would expect confidence bands to be larger where I have fewer data points and fewer certainty?

Can anyone walk through this?

[image: Logistic Regression Model with 95% Confidence Intervals]

Comment: Can you add your code? So anyone can give a try to help you